# Zlib keeps causing problems in new ubuntu server/rvm/gemset

Tags: ruby, rvm, zlib

I've just installed RVM on a new ubuntu 10.04 LTS server and one ruby, 1.9.2-p180.  I've made a new gemset in my project folder, which has a Gemfile.  I realised that in order to install the gems in the gemfile, i need to install bundler, so i did

```
gem install bundler
```

but, i get this error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
  no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
  uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

I googled around a bit and tried this:

```
rvm pkg install zlib
```

which installed ok but didn't solve the problem.  I also tried installing the rake gem but got the same error trying to do that.

Kind of stuck...any suggestions?  thanks, max

EDIT - btw, i can install the bundler gem fine outside of rvm, ie using system ruby.

EDIT2 - I got past this problem by removing the version of ruby, then installing it again with zlib:

```
rvm remove 1.9.2-p180
rvm install 1.9.2-p180 -C --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Now i can install bundler and all my gems ok.  Hooray.  *Except*, when i try to open my rails env (with `rails s`, `rails c` or `rake db:create`) i get this fatal error:

```
/home/max/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/
1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 
/lib/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.3.3' not found (required by 
/home/max/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/zlib.so) - 
/home/max/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/zlib.so (LoadError)
```

So, still not out of the woods zlib-wise.  I don't know why zlib is causing such problems, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Sorted it!

Running `locate libz` gives me

```
/home/max/.rvm/src/zlib-1.2.5/libz.a
/home/max/.rvm/src/zlib-1.2.5/libz.so
/home/max/.rvm/src/zlib-1.2.5/libz.so.1
/home/max/.rvm/src/zlib-1.2.5/libz.so.1.2.5
/home/max/.rvm/usr/lib/libz.a
/home/max/.rvm/usr/lib/libz.so
/home/max/.rvm/usr/lib/libz.so.1
/home/max/.rvm/usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.5
/lib/libz.so.1
/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3
```

I just noticed that the version of libz in lib is 1.2.3.3 while the version i installed with rvm is 1.2.5.  Is this the problem perhaps? In the /lib folder, `zlib.so.1` is symlinked to it's neighbour file `libz.so.1.2.3.3`.

I tried symlinking it to `/home/max/.rvm/usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.5` instead:

```
sudo rm /lib/libz.so.1
sudo ln -s /home/max/.rvm/src/zlib-1.2.5/libz.so.1 /lib/libz.so.1
```

and, that seems to have worked...  i still don't really understand exactly what went wrong, though, so would welcome a more insightful solution/explanation :)